# How do I find out whether a locale uses 12 or 24 hour time in Java?

Tags: java, time, locale

In Java, I want to print just the time of day in hours and minutes and want it to correctly switch between, e.g., "13:00" and "1:00 PM" according to the locale. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The locale doesn't explicitly specify whether 12 or 24 hour time formats are preferred.  Rather, locale specific date formats are handled by the locale defining the formats directly.

- If you simply want to use the "locale preferred" time format, just call one of the three [`DateFormat.getTimeInstance(...)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) static methods, and use whatever `DateFormat` it returns.
- If you have a `SimpleDateFormat` instance in your hands, you could (if you were prepared to do a significant amount of coding) call [`toPattern()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#toPattern()) and parse the resulting pattern to see if it used a 12 or 24 hour dates ... or neither.  You could even tweak the pattern to use the "other" form and then call [`applyPattern(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#applyPattern(java.lang.String)) to alter the format.

Comment: Thank you very much! Since I really just want to print it `DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, someLocale)` did the trick for me. I certainly don't look forward to a situation where I need to actually know what time format is used :p.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [java.text.DateFormat](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) class to create the correct output of the given time.

As from the API:

> To format a date for the current Locale, use one of the static factory methods:
>
> ```
> myString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(myDate);
> ```

You just use the `getTimeInstance()` method and call the `format()` method on the returned DateFormat object

Answer (score -1):

I have written small function which detects whether current locale uses 24 or 12 hours:

```
public static boolean is24HourLocale() {
    String output = SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(new Date());
    if (output.contains(" AM") || output.contains(" PM")) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work if you have a different default locale, for which the AM/PM markers are different.